# WS2811 timing issue

Tags: microcontroller, led

[The datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) says if the data line stays low for more than 50µs then the data will latch. From my testing I found that in between two 24-bit packets I cannot wait more than 2-3µs, else it will latch up some unwanted data within this 3µs time.

Has anybody experienced this?

The reason I asked, I want to load 24-bit color data from a single micro controller without using any additional large memory chips.

After feeding the 24 bits I'm arranging the next 24-bit data quickly (this may take 3-4µs) to the strip. So going to use that 50µs spare time, but it cannot do, it will add noise within 2-3µs.

Comment: What do you mean "it will add noise"?

Comment: If I stay low for more than 3uS it will make latch whatever the 24bits consists.

Comment: The datasheet says that the longest data pulse should be 2.15uS.  If you don't meet that then you would expect invalid data.

Comment: Do you always take the data line high as soon as T0L or T1L period is completed?  From my use of the 2811 I seem to remember that the T0L and T1L time is more critical than the T0H and T1H.

Comment: Hi thanks.After T0L or T1L period is completed I wont take the DATA line high.I just keep it low.Is it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The English in the datasheet is terrible. I think you are referring to this sentence at the bottom of page 1:

> IC sent PWM data that received justly to OUTR, OUTG, OUTB port, after receive a low voltage reset signal the time retain over 50us.

and the table at the bottom of page 3 which says

```
RES     low voltage time      Above 50 μs
```

All this means is that to apply a reset (so that the receivers know that a new sequence is about to start) you need to hold the data line low for > 50 μs.

[image]

*Figure 1. Timing diagram.*

If you can get the next set of data ready in 3 - 4 μs then you should be fine.

Comment: If the OP is not immediately taking the data line high after T0L or T1L time, then the 3-4 μs will make the data invalid, won't it?

Comment: From reading other posts on the topic in the past it seemed to me that the chips are quite tolerant of variations in the low times. Whether or not this is true of all versions of the chips I don't know. I see from your comment under the question that you think it's the opposite. Hmmm.

Comment: I will have to have a look at my code tonight to see if I am correct.  It will be useful to know which state the OP's data line is in during the 3-4 μs.

Comment: My Data line is in LOW state during 3-4uS.In other words after every 24 bits my data line is LOW.Is it wrong?

Comment: Just checked my code.  I have the more precise timing on the high periods and leave the data line low until processing the next led data, so you were correct.  I do think that the 3-4 uS may be a little too long though.

Comment: Yes, it's difficult to know when the datasheet is so vague about the internal workings.

Comment: @Joseph143: If this is a one-off job then I would try it with a reasonable length string of LEDs and add in  an extra 2 μs delay to see if it works. If so then remove the delay and you know that you've got that much safety margin. If you could post your findings that would be helpful to us.

Answer (score 2):

Datasheet describes timings in terms of min/max times for a given
bit, but [some](https://wp.josh.com/2014/05/15/going-nsa-on-pixel-conversations/) reverse engineering efforts, and even some [official
WS datasheets](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/214694/WS2812D_Datasheet-English.pdf) indicate WS281x chips have an internal RC and
timings are dependent on sampling of data line by internal logic clocked by the RC.

Then if we reverse-engineer the implementation, we get to this definition:

- Cycle time is ~200ns (RC is not precise, so its actual period is heavily dependent on temperature)
- Reset timing is at least 64 cycles, then reset time is actually closer to 13us. (and datasheet saying reset should be "at least 50us" conforms to this).
- Staying "high" on DIN more than reset time will not trigger a reset for one LED alone, but will actually trigger a reset for all the other LEDs but he first in the strip, because LEDs only propagate high value when they "see" the low level. (when DIN is stuck high on a LED, DOUT is low).

Overall, You should not experience problems with inter-bit "low" level lasting 2-3us.

You should probably ensure you microcontroller is not handling interrupt (like timer ?) from time to time, inserting jitter in bitstream generation.

Comment: Thanks.I'll Do as suggested.